# create mass symbolic links to all subfolders

Tags: linux, centos

I have tried to create symbolic links to all sub-folders by using 1 command

```
/newfolder/subfolders* /oldfolder/subfolders*
```

link all sub folders* to new folder
i have tried

```
ln -s /newfolder/subfolders* /oldfolder/subfolders*
```

any solution to fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `xargs` and `find`:

```
 pushd oldfolder
 find ./ -type d ! -name . -print | xargs -I{} ln -s '/oldfolder/{}' '/newfolder/{}';
 popd
```